# Next.js: get html from external URL on the clients side (client side scraping)

Tags: reactjs, web-scraping, axios, next.js, fetch

I'd love to create React Next.js project that accepts any URL and displays some of the HTML code that the external page has. For example, displaying and filtering image search results of Duck Duck Go.
All of this is done **on the client's computer. No serverside work is included.**

The problem I ran into was no matter how I tried to get the data from the external site my browser refused to display the result.

**The most annoying thing is that almost every method I tried to console.log wrote the correct result to the terminal I run npm run dev but the browser displays an empty object instead!**

Please help I'm lost.

1. The first thing was using an **Axios library** [duckduckgo-images-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/duckduckgo-images-api) that uses Axios with XMLHttpRequest under the hood to get images and their details. It resulted in the well-known *origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response."* I tried to add `headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',`
   **Logged to the terminal but not to the page.**
2. Using **fetch directly**

```
fetch('https://website.com/', { mode: 'no-cors' })
    .then((result) => {
    return result.text();
    })  
    .then((content) => {
        console.log(content)
});
```

Sometimes I got a CORB error message in chrome.
This also **logged to the terminal but not to the page.**

3. Creating a hidden **Iframe and getting its value**

```
useEffect(() => {
    const iframe = document.getElementById('conentIframe');
    const iWindow = iframe.contentWindow;
    const iDocument = iWindow.document;
    //iDocument.querySelector('body').style.color = 'red';
    console.log(iWindow.document);
}, []);

return (
    <>
        <iframe
            id='conentIframe'
            src='https://website.com/'
            width='500px'
            height='500px'
        ></iframe>
        ;
    </>
);
```

But when I get the following error: "SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:3000" from accessing a cross-origin frame."
[image: Next.js error message]
**Also logged to the terminal but not to the page.**

Please help me I'm lost in this external fetch hell and I don't find any useful data for this :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out accessing websites like this is just not allowed by the rules of modern browsers due to security reasons.